# How can I split parts of a bash variable separated with tabs?

Tags: bash, tabs, quotes

I want to extract the fields in a bash script variable named $DequeuedItem. Fields are tab-delimited.

I tried with the following sentence:

`DequeuedItemF1=$(echo $DequeuedItem | cut -f1)`

But DequeuedItemF1 gets the whole $DequeuedItem, and it seems that tabs become regular spaces.  Is the echo command doing a conversion of the tabs before the stream reaches the cut command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `echo` an unquoted variable, tabs are changed to spaces.  Double-quotes will preserve the tabs:

```
DequeuedItemF1=$(echo "$DequeuedItem" | cut -f1)
```

If the `DequeuedItem` contains no internal spaces, you could also use

```
DequeuedItemF1=$(echo $DequeuedItem | cut -d\  -f1)
```

but the first option is both clearer and more robust.  (Note that there are two spaces after the backslash.  The backslash escapes the first space, which becomes the delimiter for `cut`, and the second space separates the `-d` option from the `-f` option.  Confusing, and all the more reason to use the other choice!)

Comment: ...or `-d" "`/`-d " "` which is a little less confusing.

Comment: @pst Yes, that's a bit more readable, but it still suffers from the same robustness problem.  That's one of the nice things about linux: you almost never run out of alternatives.  :-)